# Slower boot after installation with encrypted home directory

Tags: boot, 15.04, encryption, performance, swap

I have installed **Ubuntu 15.04** x64 recently.

I have observed that in comparison to non-encrypted installation, the installation with encrypted home directory results in slower boot time: 
without encrypted home folder (hence unencrypted swap partition) it takes **one iteration** of preloader animation to boot, but with encrypted home directory and swap it takes **3-5 iterations**, so it is significantly slower.

**It is normal in that case?**

I have thought that nowadays processors (for example my intel i3) should manage encrypted data faster, I mean the effort should be non significant.

Comment: It is normal. It takes some time to read data from disk and decrypt it.

Answer (score 0):

It behaves fine under normal circumstances it will bring your machine to its knees when doing any kind of **intense file operations**.

While encryption for sure will add overhead, encrypting the home partition should not have a big impact on your system's performance.

Most of the programs you run are read brom `/bin` or `/usr`, and most of the regular system writing is in `/var` or `/tmp`.

You can refer this thread for more info [What is the performance overhead of encrypted /home?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23489/what-is-the-performance-overhead-of-encrypted-home)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I am aware that in general encryption adds some overhead, but I was strictly interested only in the process of booting OS :) I was surprised that now booting takes 5 times longer than before