# installing - Installing another OS on VirtualBox

Tags: partitioning, virtualbox

I'll be installing Android OS on VirtualBox.
I currently have Ubuntu 15.10 and when I installed it, I've chosen to have a crypt system (? this is like having a password request  for the hard drive every time you turn on the laptop) 
. I know that I'll do the partition later in the installation.

So, would I have an issue about the installation or is it fine to do?

Comment: There's nothing special about Virtualbox, it will work just like any other software would. As usual with encryption, there [may be a performance hit](http://askubuntu.com/questions/23489/what-is-the-performance-overhead-of-encrypted-home)

Comment: @bain: I believe your comment holds the answer to this question. Can you please convert it to one? Ping me for an upvote!

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing special about Virtualbox, it will work just like any other software would. As usual with encryption, there [may be a performance hit](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23489/what-is-the-performance-overhead-of-encrypted-home).